# Output vader sentiment scores in columns based on dataframe rows of tweets

Tags: python, pandas, vader

I have a dataframe that contains rows of tweets and i would like to create 4 columns of the scores 'positive', 'negative', 'neutral' and 'compound' based on the content of each row using vader sentiment analysis.

I looked up different posts but i couldnt figure it out for my exact case. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I actually found a simple solution to do it through list comprehensions for anyone facing the same problem:

```
analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
df['compound'] = [analyzer.polarity_scores(x)['compound'] for x in df['tweet']]
df['neg'] = [analyzer.polarity_scores(x)['neg'] for x in df['tweet']]
df['neu'] = [analyzer.polarity_scores(x)['neu'] for x in df['tweet']]
df['pos'] = [analyzer.polarity_scores(x)['pos'] for x in df['tweet']]
```

Comment: Thank you for your easy to use solution.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This is simple and it works, but it means running the analyzer 4 times, getting back complete answers each time. Any way to take the dict that is returned and assign it to a set of new columns?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
df['rating'] = df['tweets'].apply(analyzer.polarity_scores)
pd.concat([df.drop(['rating'], axis=1), df['rating'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have done same type of work using Vader for sentiment analysis in python 3. Take a look you may find a way of how it possible to perform what you need.

```
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
import time
analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

pos_count = 0
pos_correct = 0

with open("D:/Corona_Vac/pythonprogramnet/Positive BOW.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f.read().split('\n'):
        vs = analyzer.polarity_scores(line)
        if not vs['neg'] > 0.1:
            if vs['pos']-vs['neg'] > 0:
                pos_correct += 1
            pos_count +=1


neg_count = 0
neg_correct = 0

with open("D:/Corona_Vac/pythonprogramnet/Positive BOW.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f.read().split('\n'):
        vs = analyzer.polarity_scores(line)
        if not vs['pos'] > 0.1:
            if vs['pos']-vs['neg'] <= 0:
                neg_correct += 1
            neg_count +=1

print("Positive accuracy = {}% via {} samples".format(pos_correct/pos_count*100.0, pos_count))
print("Negative accuracy = {}% via {} samples".format(neg_correct/neg_count*100.0, neg_count))
```

Hope you may fix. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like some others, I disliked the idea of multiple iterations (for each score type), and made a convenient helper method to handle the task slightly faster using "apply":

```
def Apply_SentimentIntensityAnalyzer(df: pd.DataFrame,col_name: str ):
    sia = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
    # Example usage:
    # sia.polarity_scores('I am so happy!')
    # {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.318, 'pos': 0.682, 'compound': 0.6468}

    def feature_engineer(dataframe: pd.DataFrame, col_name: str = 'text'): # -> pd.DataFrame:
        dataframe[f'sia_{col_name}_neg'] = dataframe[col_name].apply(lambda x: sia.polarity_scores(x)["neg"] )
        dataframe[f'sia_{col_name}_neu'] = dataframe[col_name].apply(lambda x: sia.polarity_scores(x)["neu"] )
        dataframe[f'sia_{col_name}_pos'] = dataframe[col_name].apply(lambda x: sia.polarity_scores(x)["pos"] )
        dataframe[f'sia_{col_name}_compound'] = dataframe[col_name].apply(lambda x: sia.polarity_scores(x)["compound"] )

    feature_engineer(df,col_name)
```

For newer versions, you could use a one-liner:

```
def Apply_SentimentIntensityAnalyzer(df: pd.DataFrame,col_name: str ):
    sia = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
    # sia.polarity_scores('I am so happy!')
    # {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.318, 'pos': 0.682, 'compound': 0.6468}

    def get_polarity_tuple(text: str ):
        ps = sia.polarity_scores(text)
        return ( ps["neg"],ps["neu"],ps["pos"],ps["compound"] )

    def feature_engineer(dataframe: pd.DataFrame, col_name: str = 'text'): # -> pd.DataFrame:
       dataframe[[f'sia_{col_name}_neg',f'sia_{col_name}_neu',f'sia_{col_name}_pos',f'sia_{col_name}_compound']] = df.apply(lambda row: get_polarity_tuple(row.text), axis='columns', result_type='expand')

    feature_engineer(df,col_name)
```

Sample use:

```
Apply_SentimentIntensityAnalyzer(df,'text')
print(df)

                          text  sia_text_neg  sia_text_neu  sia_text_pos  sia_text_compound
0                I love my dog         0.000         0.323         0.677             0.6369
1               I hate Mondays         0.787         0.213         0.000            -0.5719
2  I am not interested in this         0.361         0.639         0.000            -0.3089
```